# WPF DataGrid: Disallow multiple row highlighting

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How can I make the data grid not allow the user to select multiple rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SelectionMode attribute:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgName" SelectionMode="Single">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Well don't I feel stupid. I saw that too, and for some reason just assumed that Single was the default.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to me all the time... :)